# Can I disable pasting a newline character in my terminal?

Tags: terminal, clipboard

I'm using ZSH on Mac OS if that is important. When doing some manual cherry picking on branches in git, I sometimes would like to type `git checkout origin/develop --<path>` where I copy and paste from gitlab. However for some reason sometimes the copy and paste feature seems to fail but then there is a newline for some reason on the clipboard and it checks out the branch. I would like to prevent that.

Comment: I just add a comment char `#` (`#git checkout origin/develop --<path>`) then paste/edit command line then remove `#`. If there is a newline in pasted text or I accidentaly depress CR i just press arrow-up and continue editing.

Comment: If you use iTerm, it will warn you about pasting a newline and offer to remove it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqlaq.png

Comment: @muru Is it possible without using iTerm? I use the Terminal function of PHPStorm a lot

Comment: Modern versions of zsh enable _bracketed paste_ by default: when you paste a newline, it pastes a newline, it doesn't immediately run the command. This requires support from the terminal. If your terminal doesn't have this feature, I recommend that you switch to a better one.

Comment: Damn I just realized as a `vim` user I can't disable newlines when I want to paste into a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with iTerm as follows.
I chose `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`V` as my hotkey when programming the following as that is used in Chrome and other applications to be "paste as plain text."

### Option 1: Strip all new lines

`Preferences` -> `Keys` (tab) -> `+` (button) -> Action: `Paste...` -> `Remove newlines` (checkbox checked).

[image: Option 1: Remove newlines]

Pasting the following:

```
asdf
asdf
```

Will result in this:

```
asdfasdf
```

### Option 2: Replace new lines with spaces via regex

`Preferences` -> `Keys` (tab) -> `+` (button) -> Action: `Paste...` -> `Replace` (checkbox checked) and enter the following:

`(\r\n|\r|\n)` ->   (a space character).

[image: Option 2: Replace new lines with spaces via regex]

Pasting the following:

```
asdf
asdf
```

Results in this (this is my preference over Option 1 above):

```
asdf asdf
```

It is still safe (the command won't execute, but it is more readable in case there are multiple lines).

Comment: Will this work if you trigger paste via the middle mouse button instead of the keyboard?